# content consists of more divs

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The problem is when the content consists of more divs, nested divs like this:

```html
 <div class="box" id="customer-login">Content <div class="bl-2">more stuff</div>more contents</div>
```

Any ideas on how I make my regexp work with nested tags?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use regex to parse XML, use DOM. Allow me to recommend this article: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8412989/5290909

Comment: Where you mentioned regex?

Answer (score 0):

Try a parser instead:

```
require_once "simple_html_dom.php";
$text = 'foo <div id="t1">Content <div>more stuff</div></div> bar <div>even more</div> baz  <div id="t2">yes</div>';
$html = str_get_html($text);
foreach($html->find('div') as $e) {
    if(isset($e->attr['id']) && preg_match('/^t\d++/', $e->attr['id'])) {
        echo $e->outertext . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<div id="t1">Content <div>more stuff</div></div>
<div id="t2">yes</div>
```

Download the parser here:http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Edit: More for my own amusement I tried to do it in regex. Here's what I came up with:

```
$text = 'foo <div id="t1">Content <div>more stuff</div></div> bar <div>even more</div>
      baz <div id="t2">yes <div>aaa<div>bbb<div>ccc</div>bbb</div>aaa</div> </div>';
if(preg_match_all('#<div\s+id="t\d+">[^<>]*(<div[^>]*>(?:[^<>]*|(?1))*</div>)[^<>]*</div>#si', $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

[Refer this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721223/php-regexp-for-nested-div-tags)