# Inserting a div into a HTML file using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Using PHP, I'm trying to add a div in parsed HTML, with the insertion location depending on an existing tag's ID.

I get a generated HTML file (which I have no control of) that is basically read-only.
My job is to get that HTML file, add a few divs (buttons and other stuff), and resend it back.

This is where it gets a little bit tricky: where I need to add the divs (the ones I'm adding with buttons and stuff) depends on a div ID that can appear multiple times in the HTML file.

In order for my added div to work properly, it must be added before the parent div of the tagged, identifiable div.

Simply put:

```
... some html

<--- where i want to put our lovely div

<div> // no  tags no info just a simple div

    <div id="myId">
        ... some html
    </div>

</div>

... some html
```

Comment: an example would be nice...

Comment: Well im trying to find a way to search for a tag in a html file get parent tag and insert before it a string of code.


the get the parent tag is the one troubling me

Comment: Why not structure an if/else statement? If ($divID === 'abc') { insert ... } else { do something instead }

Comment: Probelm is the html file itself may have multiple variations and multitude  of the div with `myTag` occurences  i have 0 control of the html all i can do is parse it as it is add elements (my problem now)

Comment: take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721223/php-regexp-for-nested-div-tags

Comment: it is mandatory to use PHP ? Because it will be a lot easier with Javascript.

Comment: @dios231 i have other stuff that i must do with PHP but i can make it work with Js  If there is a way i would appreciate the help

Comment: an "id" should only appear once - if you are getting a file where ids "appear multiple times in the HTM", that would be invalid html and it's not going to make parsing it any easier.  aside from that, your absolute best option, imo would be to use PHP's native DOMDocument: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: @billynoah yeah i know about the repeating ids there is a lot of problems like that that im trying to resolve one at a time (old undocumented program)
For now im searching for a temporary solution so workflow won't stop
Ty will see if i can figure out something out of that

Comment: @Z3R0 - i understand, what i've offered below is a bit better than a temporary solution and if you take time to learn DOMDocument it'll be a great tool to do all kinds of other fun stuff with html and php :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your absolute best option, imo would be to use PHP's native DOMDocument: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

There's quite a learning curve to this so I worked up something that should get you going in the right direction - if not provide a solution altogether.  I've included line by line comments here to explain each step:

```php
// the filename you want to parse
$filename = './test.html';

// an array of replacement html snippets and the id of the child element.
// html will be inserted before parent of each child with a matching ID as you described
$replacements = [
    [
        'id'     => 'myId',
        'insert' => '<button>Insert before parent of #myId</button>'
    ],
    [
        'id'     => 'myId2',
        'insert' => '<button>Insert before parent of#myId2</button>'
    ]
];

// instantiate DOMDocument and read the html file
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('./test.html');

// get an array of all dom elements
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

// iterate through dom elements
foreach($elements as $element) {

    // check if this element has an 'id' attribute
    if ($element->hasAttribute('id')) {

        // iterate through replacement array
        foreach ($replacements as $i => $replacement) {

            // if element's id is a match then add this node to our array
            if ($element->getAttribute('id') == $replacement['id']) {
                $replacements[$i]['nodes'][] = $element;
            }
        }
    }
}

// iterate through replacements again
foreach ($replacements as $replacement) {

    // iterate through nodes we found which matched
    foreach ($replacement['nodes'] as $node) {

        // create a DOMDocument node from an html string
        $html = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
        $html->appendXML($replacement['insert']);

        // insert this node before parent
        $node->parentNode->parentNode->insertBefore($html,$node->parentNode);
    }
}

// output the revised html
echo $dom->saveHTML();

// note - if your html doesn't have <html> and <body> tags they will be automatically added by DOMDOcument
// you can work around this and get only body innerhtml with something like this
echo str_replace(['<body>','</body>'],'',$dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)));
```

I created a test document with the following html called **test.html**. I intentionally used `myId` twice to demonstrate that this will in fact match every element regardless of validity:

```html
<div> // no  tags no info just a simple div
    <div id="myId">
        ... some html
    </div>
</div>

<div> // no  tags no info just a simple div
    <div id="myId2">
        ... some html
    </div>
</div>

<div> // no  tags no info just a simple div
    <div id="myId">
        ... some html
    </div>
</div>
```

The php code above outputs the following:

```html
<button>Insert before parent of #myId</button><div> // no  tags no info just a simple div
    <div id="myId">
        ... some html
    </div>
</div>

<button>Insert before parent of #myId2</button><div> // no  tags no info just a simple div
    <div id="myId2">
        ... some html
    </div>
</div>

<button>Insert before parent of #myId</button><div> // no  tags no info just a simple div
    <div id="myId">
        ... some html
    </div>
</div>
```