# capture nested tags with regex?

Tags: python, regex, nested

```
s = '''<p>Plain text, <i>italicized phrase,
 <i>italicized subphrase</i>, <b>bold
 subphrase</b></i>, <i>other italic
 phrase</i></p>'''

r1 = r'''(?sx)(
<i>(
(?!</?i>).
|
<i> ( (?!</?i>). )* </i>
)*</i>
)'''
```

I use r1 pattern to capture `<i>...</i>` in string s.
But `<i>italicized subphrase</i>` can't be captured.
Why?

**I'm not dealing with HTML code really, but something similar with HTML's nest structure! I'm just taking these codes for example.**
My problem is how to capture both nested and nesting tags in only one layer nest structure.

Comment: Use a reasonable HTML parser...

Comment: Argh, please do not try to parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Semi-related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/133601/646543
Tangentally-related-but-funny: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/646543 (see answers)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076219/regular-expression-for-nested-tags-innermost-to-make-it-easier

Comment: @Tuim I'm not dealing with HTML code really, but something similar with HTML nest. My problem is how to capture both nested and nesting tags in only one layer nest structure.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a regular expression, and matching XML with such expressions get [too complicated, too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Please don't make it hard on yourself and use a HTML parser instead, Python has several to choose from:

- [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a popular 3rd party library
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a fast and feature-rich C-based library.

ElementTree example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('filename.html')
for elem in tree.findall('i'):
    print ElementTree.tostring(elem)
```

Comment: I'm just take this HTML for example and I'm not really parse HTML code.

Comment: And my problem is how to capture both nested and nesting tags(not HTML tag not something similar defined by myself) with only one layer nest?

Comment: @ThunderEX: You *should* parse HTML code. Nested tags in regular expressions are *hard*, and you really want to avoid that pain.

Comment: For lxml it does not matter what the tags are, as long as there are tags.