# Regex to match only innermost delimited sequence

Tags: regex, perl, delimiter, regex-lookarounds

I have a string that contains sequences delimited by multiple characters: `<<` and `>>`. I need a regular expression to only give me the *innermost* sequences. I have tried lookaheads but they don't seem to work in the way I expect them to.

Here is a test string:

```
'do not match this <<but match this>> not this <<BUT NOT THIS <<this too>> IT HAS CHILDREN>> <<and <also> this>>'
```

It should return:

```
but match this
this too
and <also> this
```

As you can see with the third result, I can't just use `/<<[^>]+>>/` because the string may have one character of the delimiters, but not two in a row.

I'm fresh out of trial-and-error. Seems to me this shouldn't be this complicated.

Comment: Theoretically, this kind of problem (stack-ish, depending on some intermediate state, etc) needs a more expressive grammar than a regular.

Comment: Regular expressions can only parse regular grammars.  This is not a regular grammar.

Comment: Perl's regular expression aren't at all regular, and can parse this just fine.

Comment: @miku, @cdhowie: Since he wants the inner brackets and not the outer ones, there actually is a regular grammar for it. `/<<(?:[^<>]+|<[^<]|>[^>])*>>/`

Comment: @ikegami: it's more complicated than that; that doesn't match all of `<<<>>`

Comment: @ysth, Indeed, though still possible to do using a regular grammar. Just a lot more wordy.

Comment: hmm, does it work if you just end `*?<?>>` ?  no, that still leaves the > alternation potentially getting the < from a << incorrectly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@matches = $string =~ /(<<(?:(?!<<|>>).)*>>)/g;
```

`(?:(?!PAT).)*` is to patterns as `[^CHAR]*` is to characters.

Answer (score 6):

```
$string = 'do not match this <<but match this>> not this <<BUT NOT THIS <<this too>> IT HAS CHILDREN>> <<and <also> this>>';
@matches = $string =~ /(<<(?:[^<>]+|<(?!<)|>(?!>))*>>)/g;
```

Comment: Yessss... I knew there was a way. You win the Perl PGA Tour, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to use `split` for the job:

```
my $str = 'do not match this <<but match this>> not this <<BUT NOT THIS <<this too>> IT HAS CHILDREN>> <<and <also> this>>';
my @a = split /(?=<<)/, $str;
@a = map { split /(?<=>>)/, $_ } @a;

my @match = grep { /^<<.*?>>$/ } @a;
```

Keeps the tags in there, if you want them removed, just do:

```
@match = map { s/^<<//; s/>>$//; $_ } @match;
```